# Bootstrap table (already populated) converted to kendo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, kendo-grid

I think I am in a difficult situation, I had read that you can convert an html table into a kendo grid easily. So i developed the whole bootstrap table, in MVC application and populated it with data as follows.

```
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)

</div>
```

_MapDetailsList.cshtml has table element

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails">

<thead>
      <tr> ... </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
         <tr> ... </tr>
           @{
               var rowIndex = 3;
            foreach (ShortStudent geStudent in Model.students)
            {
               <tr> ... </tr>
             rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It has complicated logics for populating the table cells inside the "tr" tags with data from Model.students in razor.

After this i converted it to a kendoGrid my script is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    $("#MapDetails")
        .kendoGrid(
    {

       sortable: true,
       dataSource: {
           pageSize: 5
       },
       pageable: true,
           resizable: true,
           columnMenu: true,
           scrollable:true,
           navigatable: true,
           editable: "incell"

    });

 });
```

(My no. of columns and their content (headers too) change on every reload.)

Now this works fine until i reload the grid, so the newer header and data rows appear as a data row. and the original/first-time header is fixed on top. In other words the newer html table is nested inside the original one.

Now Telerik suggested the following to me which i am not sure how to implement.

1. Create a wrapper - Add an HTML element to the page in which to load a new table.
2. Initially load the table inside this wrapper and raise the grid.
3. When recreating the grid remove the wrapper of the grid and destroy the grid instance. That way the wrapper from point 1 will remain blank.
4. Using load add the new table inside the wrapper and recreate the grid.

I just need to know how exactly to implement this suggestion into my code.

What i cannot understand is how to recreate all the razor logic within my table element?

Comment: What exactly do you need the table for? Responsiveness? Why not just roll with the grid control out the gate with your model? Forgive me if this was listed somewhere in the description.

Answer (score 0):

As told by kendo support team, this kind of implementation has limitations. when it comes to customizing column locking and setting width etc. However, here is how you can create a wrapper and then reload table inside the grid.

```
 var kendoGrid = $("#MapDetails").getKendoGrid();
    if (kendoGrid) {
        kendoGrid.wrapper.remove();
        kendoGrid.destroy();
    }

    $('#mapsDiv').load(url, {...},
       function (data) {
           $("#MapDetails").kendoGrid({
               sortable: true,
               dataSource: {
                   pageSize: 2
               },
               pageable: true,
                   resizable: true,
                   columnMenu: true,
                   scrollable:true,
                   navigatable: true,
                   editable: "incell"});
```